# How to calculate $E[g|\mathcal{F}] , E[f|\mathcal{G}] $?

Tags: measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, borel-sets

$\Omega$ = [0,1] $\mathbb{B}$ is the Borel  $\sigma$-algebra and the $\mathbb{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure. If f(x) = x^2/2 , g(x) = 2(x-1/2)^2.
0
$\mathcal{F}$ = $\sigma{(f)}$  and $\mathcal{G} = \sigma{(g)}$ then what is  $E[g|\mathcal{F}] , E[f|\mathcal{G}] $ ?

As to generated sigma algebra, I only have seen the case that random variable takes discrete values. How should I understand the notion that E[f|g]?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).